What does に mean in 口止め料にこうして色々やらせてもらってる
I am uncertain about the function of に in this sentence:

口止め料にこうして色々やらせてもらってるし

I think this に indicates a reason. So, 口止め料に mean "because I receive hush money"?

(Source: she is beautiful chapter 43)

What is this from? If it is a published work, I suggest including the title and the author. It's generally a good practice to give credits when redistributing a part of the work, and can provide context (e.g. genre, period).

@naruto Thanks for linking to these duplicates. I just realized that I asked the wrong question. The root cause of my confusion lies in the verb やらせてもらってる. I initially thought the subject is the speaker himself but it seems more appropriate for 清香 to be the subject?

The subject of "receiving" is the guy. "As hush money, I'm receiving a favor of letting me do various things" → "(Instead of real money,) I've been getting various jobs from you (and they serve as hush money)".
